# Uploading A zip file to nexus using a jenkins job

Tags: maven, jenkins, zip, nexus

I have a project which uses the maven antrun plugin to generate a zip file. I want to upload this zip file to my nexus repo using my jenkins job.

The build section of my pom.xml is as follows

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-antrun-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <mkdir dir="${targetFolder}\conf"/>
                            <copy todir="${targetFolder}\conf">
                                <fileset dir="${configurationSource}"/>
                            </copy>
                            <copy file="${basedir}\worker.sh" todir="${targetFolder}"></copy>

                            <zip destfile="${project.build.directory}\${workerDeploy}.zip"
                                 basedir="${project.build.directory}"
                                 excludes="classes/** surefire/** antrun/** maven-archiver/** *.zip"/>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-jar-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>com.hp.wpp.worker.Application</mainClass>
                        <classpathPrefix>dependency/</classpathPrefix>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Class-Path>conf/</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is this project maven based?

Comment: BTW: Why not using maven-assembly-plugin instead of maven-antrun-plugin?

Comment: added syntax highlighting of pom

Comment: What's wrong with configuring Maven to do it? Then just run "mvn deploy"

Comment: Agree with the above, configure maven to do this if you're going to use maven, don't run ant in maven. It looks like maybe you're more comfortable with ant?  If so, have a look at the Aether Ant Tasks:  http://wiki.eclipse.org/Aether/Ant_Tasks#Deploying_artifacts

Comment: I found a simple way to do it. I used the mvn deploy file plugin. It uploads any file you specify.

Comment: I used Ant because I was unable to generate the zip with my requiremsnts using the maven assembly plugin